# Eliminar caracter en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema, en el ejercicio que estoy haciendo me pide ejecutar por consola lo siguiente:
Si la letra está en mayúscula, debe restar el primer dígito del segundo.
Si la letra está en minúscula, se deben agregar ambos dígitos.
Si los DÍGITOS son iguales, se debe presentar el producto entre estos dos dígitos.

El problema que tengo es que hice el ejercicio pero no debe tener ningún espaciado entre cada letra o numero ejemplo si pongo "3 A 3" esta mal tiene que estar "3A3" todo junto, se los agradeceria si me ayudaran, gracias.

```
int N = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int v1, v3;
        string v2;

        for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        {
            string[] maths = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
            v1 = Int32.Parse(maths[0]);
            v2 = maths[1];
            v3 = Int32.Parse(maths[2]);
            int total = 0;

            if (v2 == v2.ToUpper())
            {
                if (v3 == v1)
                {
                    total = v3 * v1;
                }
                else
                {
                    total = v3 - v1;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                total = v3 + v1;

            }

            Console.WriteLine(total);
        }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! cual es la entrada y cual la salida??? por lo que veo, solo estas agregando los espacios cuando v2 no es igual a v2 en mayusculas...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función `Trim()` o `Replace()`. Un ejemplo de ambas:

```
String cadena = "A B C";
cadena.Trim();
```

`Trim()` elimina los espacios en blanco de una cadena si no le agregas parámetros, puedes agregar en los paréntesis los caracteres a remover.

```
String cadena = "A B C";
cadena.Replace(" ","");
```

`Replace()` recibe como primer argumento el carácter a reemplazar y como segundo argumento el carácter que colocaras en su lugar, en este caso usamos "" para decir que remueva el carácter.

Comment: Trim elimina solo adelante y atras, no en el medio... replace funcionaria, si su cadena no tuviera mas de una palabra ;) mejor esperar que aclare un poco mas el escenario...

Comment: Gracias por el dato sobre Trim, lo desconocía.

Comment: siempre hay que leer la documentacion, ademas de probarlo ;)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la mejor respuesta es utilizar regex para eliminar todos los posibles espacios que tengas en el string:

```
Regex.Replace(operation, @"\s+", "");
```

y para demostrar lo que entendi de tu código realice esto;

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

 class MainClass {
 public static void Main (string[] args) {
            /* 
         * test of operations
         * 
         */
        // string operation ="32a5";
        string operation ="3 2 P5 ";
        //string operation ="6 k 61 ";
        //string operation = "3 a 3";

        int result = 0;
        int v1 = 0;
        int v2 = 0;
        operation = Regex.Replace(operation, @"\s+", "");
        for (int i = 0; i < operation.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!Char.IsNumber(operation[i]))
            {
                var ltra = operation[i];
                var nPos = operation.IndexOf(ltra);
                v1 = Convert.ToInt32(operation.Substring(0, nPos));
                v2 = Convert.ToInt32(operation.Substring(nPos + 1));
                if (char.IsUpper(ltra))
                {
                    result = v1 != v2 ? v1 - v2 : v1 * v2;
                }
                else
                {
                    result = v1 == v2 ? v1 + v2 : v1 * v2;
                }
            }
        }
        
        Console.WriteLine("Valor {0} de la operación entre {1} y {2}", result, v1 
    ,v2);
   }
 }
```

Ejecutandolo [aqui](https://repl.it/join/uqpjetpt-gregdorian)

Comment: No termino de entender para que hacer un for sobre una cadena en la cual solo vas a hacer una operacion una vez que entres.. por que si hay mas de una letra en la cadena esto va a tirar error.. entonces para que estaria el for? vuelvo a recomendar lo mismo que en la otra respuesta, esperar a que OP clarifique el problema...

Comment: @gbianchi Estoy de acuerdo, creo que el OP le falto especificar, el código sólo se asume que ingresa una letra, pero lo que el OP pidió fue eliminar espacios y fue lo que sugerí (Con Regex) y lo demás que realice fue como entendí lo que quería Hacer Jorge