# ¿Como pedir datos de una misma linea y sin espacios en C#?

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
string[] stringValues = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
a = Int32.Parse(stringValues[0]);
b = char.Parse(stringValues[1]);
c = Int32.Parse(stringValues[2]);
```

Lo que quiero es que el usuario digite 1 numero una letra y otro numero, Ejemplo:

> 2B4

Probé hacerlo de este modo:

```
string[] stringValues = Console.ReadLine().Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Pero tampoco funcionó.

Hay alguna forma de lograr lo que quiero? Agradezco sus comentarios y respuestas.

Comment: creo que es lo mismo que respondí aca https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/386895/24490 me dices si es algo diferente

Comment: @ger No, no parece amigo, en este caso pedimos los datos directamente desde la consola (CMD) Lo que se busca es que el usuario digite "4A5" todo junto y no salten errores

Comment: si te fijas donde dice test de operations cambiar el string por el Console.ReadLine() que definiste en tu pregunta

Comment: El primero y último número siempre será de un dígito o puede tener más? La letra siempre será una letra o pueden ser varias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes intentar hacer una depuración de caracteres que te pueden causar error, espacios dobles, espacios al final, tabuladores y principio. por si teclean:
2  B 4

string cadena = "2  B 4";
cadena = cadena.Replace(" ", "").Replace("  ", "").Replace("\t", "");

Edit para la solución:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=netcore-3.1

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string s = "AaBbCcDd";
      char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();
      Console.WriteLine("Original string: {0}", s);
      Console.WriteLine("Character array:");
      for (int ctr = 0; ctr < chars.Length; ctr++)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("   {0}: {1}", ctr, chars[ctr]);
      }
   }
}

// The example displays the following output:
//     Original string: AaBbCcDd
//     Character array:
//        0: A
//        1: a
//        2: B
//        3: b
//        4: C
//        5: c
//        6: D
//        7: d
```

Comment: El problema está en que aquí el usuario escribe "2 B 4 " y se convierte en "2B4" Lo que debería suceder es que desde el primer momento se pueda escribir "2B4" sin que salga error

Comment: Hola, lo que tienes que hacer es primero quitar los espacios, luego ese string te quedara como "2b4", luego ese string lo descompones en caracteres con .toCharArray()

string s = "AaBbCcDd";
      char[] chars = s.ToCharArray();
      Console.WriteLine("Original string: {0}", s);
      Console.WriteLine("Character array:");
      for (int ctr = 0; ctr < chars.Length; ctr++)
      {
         Console.WriteLine("   {0}: {1}", ctr, chars[ctr]);
      }

Comment: Ya edite mi respuesta original, checa el código y pruebalo, si te sirvió marcalo como solución :D